# Not Rendering the Default Application Layout in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout, default

I am an entry developer in Rails and I am doing system study of an Application developed in Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.0.3. In my App, I have **application_controller** with an **application.html.erb** layout and a **home_controller** with a **home_html.erb** layout along with CRUD views. Then in my **routes.rb**, the default route is set as given below along with resourceful routing for home.

**root :to => 'home#index'**

**resources :home**

In **application.html.rb**, we have default layout to be rendered inside which the other views need to be inserted using **<%= yield %>**. But I have another layout called **home.html.erb** whose contents are the same as that of the **application.html.erb**. When I run the app, the default layout is loaded from **home.html.erb** instead of **application.html.erb**. What could be the reason?

Comment: care to explain why downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By Default, a **controller** will first look for a template with the
>   same name inside the **layouts** folder and if not found, it will
>   render the default **application** layout.

In this scenario, when **home_controller** index action is performed, the layout rendered is **home.html.rb** along with the view content since **home.html.rb** is with the same naming format as of the controller. When I changed it to **homes.html.rb**, the controller takes **application.html.rb** from the layouts folder. 
So the solution is,

> Just remove **home.html.erb** from **views/layouts/** folder. It will
>   automatically render **application.html.erb** by default.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5):

In your controller write

```
   class TetsController < ApplicationController
      layout "layout_name"
      #...
    end
```

Comment: I dont want to render any specific layout. I need Application layout to be rendered and it should be done by default. Right? And that is what not happening for me. We haven't specified layout 'home' in home_controller. Then why it is rendering 'home.html.erb' layout?

Comment: This is may be because your controller name is 'HomeController' not 'HomesController'. Your controller name singular but rails convention is our controller class is plural like ProductsController, BooksController etc...

Comment: Then why application_controller and why not applications_controller?

Comment: I appreciate your question but didn't know the exact reason behind this. :(

Comment: Over a year later, you saved me from pulling my hair out.  I thank you heartily.

Answer (score 2):

By default application layout will be called to all of your controllers, but if you want to render a specific layout you should do this

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
   layout 'home'
end
```

HTH

Comment: I dont want to render any specific layout. I need Application layout to be rendered and it should be done by default. Right? And that is what not happening for me. We haven't specified layout 'home' in home_controller. Then why it is rendering 'home.html.erb' layout?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstand your question. Actually the preference is if you have a layout in the same name as your controller, then it gets the preference. So since you have a 'home' layout, it gets preference over 'application' layout. So you have two options , 1) call the 'application' layout from home_controller. 2) remove the 'home' layout (I think (1) is more practical)

Comment: Can you please clarify how the (1) could be a good option as we have application.html.erb and home.html.erb with the same contents? Also why do we need an explicit call to application layout from home_controller as it will be done by default?